# Return a 401 to the JavaScript when the session has expired

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 application which uses forms authentication.

Forms authentication has been setup as follows in the *web.config*.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Session/LogIn"
         protection="All"
         timeout="60"
         slidingExpiration="true"
         />
</authentication>
```

When the session expires and I click on something which results in a regular HTTP call, the *Session/Login* page is shown. Which is all good.

But, when the session expires and I click on something which results in an AJAX call, the *Session/Login* page is embedded inside the HTML element which the AJAX call was going to update. i.e. if the AJAX call was to update a div with an id of *123*, and because the session expired, then the login form will be placed inside that div.

What I would like to do is to check in the ASP.NET MVC 3 application when the session has expired. If it has, and the call is an AJAX one, then I would like to return no content as the response, and set the return status code to a 401.

In the JavaScript (using jQuery), I can then look for the unauthorised status code of 401, and redirect the user to the Login page. Something like this:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, response, settings, error) {
    if (response.status == 401) {
        window.document.location = "Login";
    }
});
```

So what I am looking for is a sure way to check that the session has expired on the C# side, and return an empty response with a status code of 401 which then the JavaScript can handle with cleanly.

Answer (score 1):

in the action that returns the login page `(Sesssion/LogIn)` check if this is an ajax request,

```
if(Request.IsAjaxRequest)
```

and if it is return a `Content("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>");` instead of `View()`

Comment: or just return statuscode 401 and end the response instead of the content string